# Get country and timestamp for the current location

Tags: c#, wpf, timezone, regioninfo

I want to know where my application is used.

Here is the code for getting the country name:

```
public string Country = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
```

Here is the code to get the timezone:

```
public void TimeStamp()
{
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    // Demonstrate ToLocalTime and ToUniversalTime.
    DateTime local = zone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.Now);

    _TimeStamp = local.ToString();
}
```

I want to see if this works for other locations and IP addresses. I have tried to change my IP address using cyperghost, but nothing changed. I live in Denmark and the code above still shows "Denmark xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx".

How can I test if this code actually works as I want it to?

Answer (score 2):

[TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns information from your current PC. So, you can change your date and timezone and check:
[image]